# Using the ts() function in R

Tags: r, time-series, dataset, trend

I am starting to work on my time series data analysis, and I have been told to use the ts() data function in R. However, my time series data doesnt follow a direct trend.

For example, the tutorials online explain how to create the time series if you have monthly, quarterly, or yearly trends. 
However, my recorded times are 0, 5, 11, 15, 20, 30, and 50.

I was wondering if anybody would have any advice on how to work around this? 
Many thanks :)

Comment: This is a irregular timeserie. There is a package **its**. https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue is that `ts` series are regularly spaced and yours is not but there are a number of approaches to get a regularly spaced `ts` class series:

1. maintain the original representation as an irregularly spaced time series using the zoo package (which can directly represent such series) or after converting to zoo use `as.ts` on it to convert to a regularly spaced series with possibly many NAs.
2. ignore the times and just use times of 1, 2, 3, ... instead.  In that case the series is regularly spaced so we can use ts.
3. discretize the data into regularly spaced intervals using the last value or average value in the interval.  In that case the series is regularly spaced so we can use ts.
4. Fit a spline to the data and pick off regularly spaced points from that giving a regularly spaced series that can be represented by ts.

If there is a natural periodicity to the series then you might need to modify how the series is represented as ts to reflect that in its frequency but as the question gave no information on this we will ignore that here.

Also depending on the precise application there might be packages that have application specific methods that could be used.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

For example,

```
# create some test data
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(35), 7)
tt <- c(0, 5, 11, 15, 20, 30, 50)

# 1. zoo series
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(m, tt)

ts1 <- as.ts(z)  # make regularly spaced ts series but with many NAs

# 2. ignore times
ts2 <- ts(m)

# 3. discretize to regularly spaced grid - z is from #1
zd <- aggregate(z, 20 * ceiling(tt/20), tail, 1)
ts3 <- as.ts(zd)

# 4.  spline 
Ls <- apply(m, 2, spline, x = tt)   # list of splines, one per column
zs <- zoo(sapply(Ls, "[[", "y"), Ls[[1]]$x)  # as single zoo object
ts4 <- unname(as.ts(zs))
```

Comment: how would I indicate that I have 3 repeats in them, it seems that whenever I put frequency=3 it divides up the values?

Comment: If x is a regularly spaced series derived using one of the alternatives in the answer then assuming you want time to start at 0 and have a frequency of 3 then use: ts(x, start = 0, frequency = 3)

Comment: The specific versions of rollapply are meant to have reduced functionality in return for some addition speed.  zoo was first released in 2002 way before github became popular in the R community.  To suggest features, the DESCRIPTION file contains contact information for the maintainer (which is not me for the zoo package)..  I have contact info on my SO profile and in the DESCRIPTION files of those R packages that I maintain (sqldf, gsubfn, nls2).  sqldf also has a google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqldf that can also used for my other packages too.

Answer (score 1):

The below code uses a dataframe built into R named `AirPassengers`, while is a ts(), when mutate it to get it to plot with GGPlot2 nicely. I believe this dataset is monthly for 12 years(144 rows), but we get it as a time series.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dff <- melt(AirPassengers)
ggplot(data = dff, aes(x = 1:length(dff[[1]]), y = dff$value)) + geom_line() + labs(x = "Time", y = "Value")
```

Please pay attention to

```
class(AirPassengers)
dff <- melt(AirPassengers)
class(dff)
```

Where the ts() becomes a data.frame.

[image]

Comment: thank you, and if my data set is gene related, do you know whether I use the raw data or the transformed data?

Comment: Maybe time on the x axis, the value on the y axis, and the entire plot will be for 1 gene, or you can plot multiple genes with different line colors on the same plot